# Creative Mode Duplication on a Laptop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am attempting to clone an item with creative mode, which would normally be done with the middle mouse button. However, I am attempting this on a laptop? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the creative mode duplication with the middle mouse button, I suggest looking into your Minecraft controls and modifying the "Pick Block" control to another key.

This can be found in options>controls>gameplay>pick block

Comment: @Diamondmist44minecraft No Problem. If it does please mark this as the accepted answer.